# Vaadin 23 frequently loses active session and user has to login again

Tags: session, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I noticed that my Vaadin 23 application often loses the active session and the user needs to log in again. Most often  it is happens on my IPhone, but on the desktop browsers it appears as well.

This is my SpringBoot application.properties:

```
vaadin.whitelisted-packages=com/example/ui
vaadin.heartbeatInterval=300
vaadin.pushLongPollingSuspendTimeout=60000
vaadin.compatibilityMode = false
```

Right now, I don't even know where to dig in order to debug this issue. I'll appreciate any help on this and provide here any additional information about my application configuration. Please help to solve this issue

Answer (score 2):

All sessions are closed after some time by default (30 minutes, approximately). This is Spring Boot's embedded servlet container default behavior.

If you want to customize this behavior, have a look at https://mvysny.github.io/vaadin-session-timeout/ which includes an in-depth explanation.

Basically, you can set the [spring.session.timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.web.spring.session.timeout) property in your application.properties file to your desired value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm testing this right now

Comment: Still see the same issue on my IPhone. Application very often logouts user and I have to re log in. What may be the reason of that?

Comment: If its only happening on your iPhone (or Android phone for that matter), it's most likely a byproduct of your device killing connections in the background as part of their many efficiency/battery saving routines.

To avoid that, I would probably use some kind of cookie/jwt token/local storage strategy to make it transparent for the end users.

Comment: Thanks. Today another user reported that this issue is present and on the desktop browser..

Comment: Looks like something wrong with my configs.. I showed my configs here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74147029/vaadin-23-unable-to-fully-reload-application-after-redeploy

Comment: I hope I found the reason of that - `
    @Override
    public SystemMessages getSystemMessages(SystemMessagesInfo systemMessagesInfo) {
        var messages = new CustomizedSystemMessages();
            messages.setSessionExpiredURL(relativeSessionExpiredUrl);
        return messages;
    }` I don't know why.. but I redirect user to logout page in my configs on each SystemMessage received..